# Overriding xml <include .../>

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Is it possible to override an attribute in xml in a  tag?

parent.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include  
        layout="@layout/button"
         android:text="HAHAHAH"
         />
</TableLayout>
```

button.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TextView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="some string" />
```

Is it possible to change "some string" into "HAHAHA"?

Comment: What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: Like abstract class in java. the button is just a container, then in parent I fill in some details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no :) "Yes", because you can override attributes in XML in general, "no" because in this case only changing `android:layout_*` attribues will take effect:

> You can also override all the layout parameters (any `android:layout_*`
>   attributes) of the included layout's root view by specifying them in
>   the  tag. For example:

```
<include android:id=”@+id/news_title”
         android:layout_width=”match_parent”
         android:layout_height=”match_parent”
         layout=”@layout/title”/>
```

> However, if you want to override layout attributes using the 
>   tag, you must override both android:layout_height and
>   android:layout_width in order for other layout attributes to take
>   effect.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html#Include

Comment: That is disappointing :(